# How can I find $\theta$, the angle between two given vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say I have been given a vector A. Another vector B is also given but at an unknown angle making angle ϴ to A. How to find  out ϴ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cos(\theta)= {{A.B}\over {\mid A\mid\mid B\mid}}$ where $A.B$ is the scalar product of $A$ and $B$